# How can I Single sign on with Cognito without Hosted UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, amplifyjs

I'm thinking of using Cognito to SSO (if one is already logged in, the other will be authenticated without login), SPA on S3, web application on ALB + EC2, and these two applications.

I added each app client under the same user pool in Cognito.
The SPA provided a login page within the app and authenticated using Amplify.Auth.signIn
For web apps, I added an authenticate action to the ALB.
When I tried it, SSO was not possible.

Authentication on the ALB side is done via the Cognito domain where the Hosted UI is located. Therefore, SSO was possible when the login process on the SPA side was performed with Amplify.Auth.federatedSignIn() on the login page on the Cognito domain + Hosted UI.

However, the login screen of Cognito domain + Hosted UI only accepts customization by replacing the logo image and CSS from the Cognito management screen, and it seems that all the wording is written in English and cannot be replaced with Japanese.

I would like to ask
・Is there a way to SSO without going through the Cognito domain + Hosted UI?
・Is there a way to use Amplify.Auth.signIn to mediate the Cognito domain and perform SSO?
・Is there a way to translate the login form on the Cognito domain + Hosted UI into Japanese?
・Is there any way to customize the Cognito domain + Hosted UI other than adding a logo and CSS on the management screen?